# How to generate and scan barcodes with aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, barcode

I have a webpage that needs to be able to generate and later read barcodes. But i cannot seem to find any small scale addon to aurelia that does even one of these. Is there any libary that does this or do i have to write my own somehow? Or can i somehow use some preexisting barcode stuff that is not directly designed for aurelia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have to find a suitable library for the task on npm.
For barcode generation, you can use this test app:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/barcodes-bxgf1

Be sure to adapt to your own bundling choice.

Comment: So there currently isnt a ready solution made for aurelia and i have to find a solution and just bundle it into my app? Fpr angular there are few that i can just install and use.

Comment: Yes. It should be as simple as npm install jsbarcode

Answer (score 0):

I used [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) in my aurelia app for reading existing bar codes.
(it's actually just a regular JS package - not specially for aurelia)

the API is kind of old (callbacks instead of promises), and overall it's a little weird (the Initialization process), but in the end it works great with little effort.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-scanner only draw back is that your website need to be https.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).